# Al ejecutar mi código se visualizan dos resultados y solo necesito uno

Tags: c++

//decuento de helado segun membresia

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float membresia,descuento,descuentodos,monto,A,B,C;
    cout<<"Ingrese el monto de su compra: ";
    cin>>monto;
    cout<<"Ingrese su tipo de membresia: ";
    cin>>membresia;

    if(membresia=A){
        cout<<"Usted obtiene un descuento del 10%";
        descuento=monto-(monto*0.10);
        cout<<"Su monto total es: "<<descuento<<endl;
    }

    if(membresia=B){
        cout<<"Usted obtiene un descuento del 20%";
        descuentodos=monto-(monto*0.20);
        cout<<"Su monto total es: "<<descuentodos<<endl;
```

Cuando ejecuto el codigo y coloco la membresia A o B (cualquiera de las dos), me sale el resultado de Las dos, me gustaría saber como logro hacer que salga un solo resultado, gracias.

Comment: el simbolo `=` es una asignación, no es una comparación. Asi que debes cambiar a `if(membresia == A){` y `if(membresia == B){`

Comment: Al hacer la modificación, no me aparecen los monto con descuento...

Comment: supongo que `membresia` puede tomar el valor de `A` o `B`, asi que alli esta tu error, tu piensas que la variabla de tipo float es el mismo que el string "A" pero no lo es.

Comment: 1) cambia `float membresia,descuento,descuentodos,monto,A,B,C;` a `float descuento,descuentodos,mont; std::string membresia;`

Comment: 2) cambia `if(membresia=A){` a `if(membresia == "A"){`; `if(membresia=B){` a `if(membresia == "B"){`

Comment: Muchas gracias, eres muy amable.